# Debugging in vscode remote containers

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

Recently I have found great feature of vsCode which is remote-containers. I decided to play with this a bit, but I got stuck on developing configuration for debugging.
At this point I am able to launch an application via debugger, but that is not sufficient for me. I would like to also have a possibility to **attach to my application process**. So far I have figured out that to be able to track process information I need to run this container with **--privildege** flag according to this doc(https://bitworks.software/en/2017-07-24-docker-ptrace-attach.html), but this only allowed me to attach to a process and breakpoints are still stay inactive.. Any ideas?

I am attaching few screenshots:

Remote container configuration:
[image]

Debugger configuration:
[image]

Inactive breakpoints:
[image]

Thanks in advance, regards!